# How can I cancel open a view controller in didSelectViewController event of UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, tabbarcontroller

I implemented UITabBarControllerDelegate event:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
    if (viewController == [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]) {
        //HERE:check some condition and cancel opening the viewController if needed
    }
}
```

In above function, after checking some condition, I would like app do some thing else (i.e opening another view controller) instead of  opening the right view controller that user selected on tab bar item. The behavior of the event:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

doesn't match with my demand.

Comment: How does shouldSelectViewController not match your demand? Simply check for your condition. If it matches do the 'something else' part and return NO, otherwise just return YES in that method.

Comment: I would like to have the light effect on bar item and open another view when user touched on it. If using the shouldSelectViewController and return NO, there is no any effect on these item.

Answer (score 1):

If returning NO from `shouldSelectViewController` isn't canceling a transition to a different tab, you have your delegate or something else wired up wrong. Check if the function is actually being reached during execution.

Testing in `shouldSelectViewController`, returning NO and presenting your other view controller is the correct way to present other views on a tab selection.